# Convert bool? to Yes/No/null string

Tags: c#, asp.net

i have an object that as a parameter bool?

i need to show it on a repeater.

```
<%# Eval("LS_Body_Connection") %>
```

i create a class

```
public static class BooleanExtensions
{
    public static string ToYesNoString(this bool value)
    {
        return value ? Resources.Yes : Resources.No;
    }
}
```

how to use it on the repeater?

i try

```
((bool)Eval("LS_Body_Connection")).ToYesNoString()
```

but it's not recognaize

'bool' does not contain a definition for 'ToYesNoString' and no extension method 'ToYesNoString' accepting a first argument of type 'bool' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

in the cs of the page i can call the extension method

when i add

```
<%@ Import Namespace="IDD.App_Code" %>
```

i get
     The call is ambiguous between the following methods or properties: 'IDD.App_Code.BooleanExtensions.ToYesNoString(bool?)' and 'IDD.App_Code.BooleanExtensions.ToYesNoString(bool?)'

Comment: Why not make your extension method work with `bool?`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

try `((bool)Eval("LS_Body_Connection")).ToYesNoString()`

And you need to import the namespace like below as Claudio's Answer

```
<%@ Import Namespace="My.Namespace.Containing.MyExtensions.Class" %>
```

Answer (score 3):

Try adding inporting the namespace where the extension method is placed

```
<%@ Import Namespace="YourNameSpace" %>
```

You'll also need to cast the `Eval` return value to bool as @Damith explained.

Comment: 1+ need to import the namespace

Answer (score 2):

Firstly, you'll need a version of `ToYesNoString` that accepts a `bool?`, rather than just `bool`, parameter.

```
public static string ToYesNoString(this bool? value)
{
    return value.HasValue ? ToYesNoString(value.Value) : null;
}
```

Then in your repeater, you should be able to cast the result of `Eval` to a `bool?`

```
(bool?)Eval("LS_Body_Connection")
```

and then either call the extension against it

```
((bool?)Eval("LS_Body_Connection")).ToYesNoString()
```

or, if that doesn't work, call the method explicitly

```
BooleanExtensions.ToYesNoString((bool?)Eval("LS_Body_Connection"))
```